# Building a login service with Firebase and SwiftUI: ViewRouter runtime error missing ancestor

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I am trying to create a simple signup/login service with swiftUI and firebase. I followed a guide I have found, but I would like to keep the logic separated from the views and put it in a separate class. Currently I have an issue related to my view router. When I try to login, the login is successful, but it doesn't redirect me to another view and it shows this runtime error:

> No ObservableObject of type ViewRouter found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for ViewRouter may be missing as an ancestor of this view."

If I put the login function in the sign in view everything works correctly. What am I missing? Here is my code.

AppDelegate

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

@main
struct Portfolio_Managment_AppApp: App {
    
    @StateObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
    
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
        
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView().environmentObject(viewRouter)
        }
    }
}
```

ViewRouter

```
import SwiftUI

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var currentScreen: Screen = .signInScreen
}

enum Screen {
    case signUpScreen
    case signInScreen
    case dashboardView
}
```

MainView

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    var body: some View {
        
        switch viewRouter.currentScreen {
        case .signInScreen:
            SignInScreen()
        case .signUpScreen:
            SignUpScreen()
        case .dashboardView:
            DashboardView()
        }
    
    }
}
```

SignInScreen

```
import Firebase
import SwiftUI

struct SignInScreen: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    @ObservedObject var signInHelper = SignInHelper()
    
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
 
            TextField("Email", text: $email)
                
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                
            
            Button("Sign In") {
                signInHelper.handleFirebaseSignIn(
                    email: email,
                    password: password)
            }       
        }
    }
```

SignInHelper

```
import Firebase
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class SignInHelper: ObservableObject {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter
    
    @State var signInProcessing = false
    @State var signInErrorMessage = ""
    
    func handleFirebaseSignIn(email: String, password: String) {
      
        self.signInProcessing = true
        
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                self.signInProcessing = false
                self.signInErrorMessage = error!.localizedDescription
                return
            }
            
            switch authResult {
            case .none:
                self.signInProcessing = false
                print("FAIL")
            case .some(_):
                self.signInProcessing = false
                print("SUCCESS")
                withAnimation {
                    self.viewRouter.currentScreen = .dashboardView
                }
            }
             
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use `@EnvironmentObject` inside another `ObservableObject` -- it's for passing the dependency to `View`s specifically.

Comment: But can I use it inside a class or just inside a view? I removed the ObservableObject but I still get the same error

Comment: You can only use use `@EnvironmentObject` inside a `View`. You must pass the dependency explicitly to anything that is not a `View` inside your hierarchy.

Comment: It might be worth considering proper dependency injection. Resolver (https://github.com/hmlongco/Resolver) is a light-weight and easy-to-use library that I've been using with great success in my own apps.

Comment: @jnpdx I am still learning Swift and I am not sure if I understood what you mean.  Do you mean initializing `ViewRouter` inside the class?

Comment: No -- I mean pass it explicitly as a parameter: `SignInHelper(viewRouter: viewRouter)`

Comment: @PeterFriese Thanks for the suggestion. I will give it a try, but it would be nicer to do it without a library